# Issue with 'zip(*train_loader_list)' causing Ubuntu GPU server crash during deep learning training on remote machine

Tags: server, pytorch, gpu

I am encountering a perplexing issue while training a deep learning model with Pytorch on a remote server. Specifically, running the line

```
zip(*train_loader_list)
```

seems to result in a server crash. My train_loader_list consists of multiple data loaders, and this line of code appears to be problematic on the remote server.

I am wondering if this might be a memory leak issue. I set the **pin_memory** parameter to **True** when creating the DataLoader. Could this be a contributing factor?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!